# Set Default Font In Silverlight Application

Tags: silverlight, xaml, fonts, styles

Does anyone know how to set the default font (color, in this case) across an entire Silverlight Application?

It's a rather large legacy application so I don't think I can take advantage of themes.  I've created styles etc but don't fancy doing this across the whole app, and them maintaining them etc..

I don't have much Silverlight/Xaml experience so please detail your answer like I'm stupid!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wrap your entire application with a `ContentControl` and specify its `Foreground`, all controls inherit the `Foreground` color. If one of your resource file specify the `Foreground` for any of your child controls, the `Foreground` should flow down to all of them... :(

Another solution is to use implicit style like in [Silverlight toolkit theme files](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Release/Silverlight4/Source/Controls.Theming.ExpressionDark/Theme.xaml). You can see one resource for the font color and this color is applied on each UI controls via [implicit style](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.style%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

**Theme.xaml**

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextBrush" Color="#FF152937" />
...
<Style TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource TextBrush}" />
```

So if your resources files override `Foreground` properties, you have to change that like in `Theme.xaml` toolkit file. Create a unique `Foreground` Brush and apply with [implicit style](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.style%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) on each control.

If someone has a better solution ???

Comment: Thanks, I tried wrapping everything in a ContentControl and setting the foreground but it didn't work for me, maybe I didn't put the tags in the right place..?  I have 
<UserControl xmlns="...>
<UserControl.Resources>...</UserControl.Resources>
<ContentControl Foreground="green">
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" >...everything here...</Grid>
</ContentControl>
</UserControl>  I was hoping there might be some code-based way to override whatever was the default font.?

Comment: `ContentControl Foreground="green"` work if no `Style` override font color. Else I think you have to use implicit style, override font properties and load this styles at last. I agree, it's a shame that there have not a general solution.